# Paste values in Excel and not formula

Tags: excel, vba

I need to paste a value in a Excel spreadsheet and not the formula.
The code I have is:

```
.Cells(lRow, 2).Formula = _
"=IF(A" & lRow & "<"" "",A" & lRow & "&TEXT(E" & lRow & ",""mmddyy""),"""")"
```

The code is merging two cells into one cell, and is different for each row.

Comment: Edited your question for you, but next time, to include a code, indent it by 4 spaces and you're all good. Anyhow, posted an answer based on how I understand your question.

Comment: @pmk interesting that you are using my answer but did not mark it as correct.  If you get a correct answer then you should mark is as such by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Ok will do thanks. I am new here but learning. Also the answer is not correct yet, still working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way to get this done would be something like:

```
Sub foo()
'Sheet1.Cells(lRow, 2).Formula = "=IF(A" & lRow & "<"" "",A" & lRow & "&TEXT(E" & lRow & ",""mmddyy""),"""")"
Dim NewValue As Variant
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If Range("A" & lRow) <> "" Then
    NewValue = Range("A" & lRow).Value & Format(Range("E" & lRow).Value, "mmddyy")
    Sheet1.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = NewValue
End If
End Sub
```

A word of warning the date values in column E should be formatted correctly for this to work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you still need the result of the formula so just add another line changing the formula to value. Something like:

```
.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = .Cells(lRow, 2).Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions.  The code you suggested does work, but it pulls a erroneous number instead of the "date". It merges Cell "A" with date in Cell "D". Your suggestion ends up merging cell "A" with generic date. Result is always "3010000". The first number (3) is correct, it is the correct value of cell "A" just the date is wrong from Cell "D"

Comment: @user2828628 It is not pulling date from `Column D`. Your original code is pulling from `Column E`. If you need the date in `Column D` then change your formula to: `"=IF(A" & lRow & "<"" "",A" & lRow & "&TEXT(D" & lRow & ",""mmddyy""),"""")"`

Comment: Yes you are correct, it is to pull from column E, not D. My mistake, sorry

Comment: @user2828628 No worries mate, no need to be sorry, but was your issue fixed?

Comment: no the issue is not fixed. It pulls the data from cell A but the date it pulls from cell E is wrong, its always 010000.

Comment: @PMK Make sure that your dates in `Column E` are actual dates else you might need another formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    lRow = 2 
    If Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
        Range("B" & lRow).Value = Range("A" & lRow).Value & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Range("D" & lRow), "mmddyy")
    Else
        Range("B" & lRow).Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```